# Symmetry-finding packages

Tags: differential-equations, group-theory

Where can I find the most up-to-date or whatever you consider to be the most useful symmetry-finding package for differential equations? I do not intend to restrict to, but would like to include those, that are designed to work within Mathematica.

I'm looking for something analogous to [this for Mathematica](http://www2.ucy.ac.cy/~mogran10/Proof/Dimas.pdf) ([software](http://www.math.upatras.gr/~spawn/) and [documentation](http://www.math.upatras.gr/~spawn/SYM_html/guide/SYMOverview.html)) or [this for Maple](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=DEtools/symgen).

Comment: A good place to start is checking papers that cite that one: http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=15595045703323033950 or cite the publication that followed it: http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=12693930071175863924 However, given that it came out in 2009, I wonder why you think there exists a more up-to-date version.

Comment: Thanks. I did check papers that cite that one. I cannot actually find the SYM package code online (obviously I could e-mail the authors). But, the package not being online usually means there is little to no documentation. So, I thought I'd ask the community if there's some well-known package that I haven't ever heard of since I'm not an expert in this domain.

Comment: You might find references to relevant Mathematica software [here](http://inside.mines.edu/~whereman/papers.html).

Comment: Thanks @DanielLichtblau. Software is [here](http://inside.mines.edu/~whereman/software.html).

Comment: I reference your question in [this related ask.sagemath.org question](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/36844/symmetry-finding/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See: Hereman's "[24 [symmetry-finding] software packages](https://inside.mines.edu/~whereman/software.html) mainly for Mathematica (commercial software), some for Macsyma* (commercial software)."

<sup>*[Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/)/[wxMaxima](https://wxmaxima-developers.github.io/wxmaxima/) are free versions.</sup>

Gerd Baumann's [*Symmetry Analysis of Differential Equations with Mathematica®*](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/6118) comes with some extra materials that include a Mathematica package called MathLie, freely downloadable [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/springer-extras/zip/2000/978-1-4612-2110-4.zip) (20.5 MB).

Also: Brian Cantwell's [*Introduction to Symmetry Analysis*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=6578)'s [IntroToSymmetry.m](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ecantwell/SymmetryAnalysisSoftware/).

Answer (score 13):

Hi all please send me an mail at spawn@math.upatras.gr or visit my web site [www.math.upatras.gr/~spawn](http://www.math.upatras.gr/~spawn), although the version on the site is not updated you can find an online version of the help files of the package. Many things have been added since my thesis. Among them, I have added command for the algebraic manipulation of the symmetries (Levi decomposition, ideals, quotient algebras, etc.), contracting conservation laws using the self adjoint property of a Differential equation and the Noether operator and constructing the equivalent algebra and finding the discrete symmetries (following an idea of Hydon in his book). Many things are still in development/testing so i need your feedback!

Answer (score 8):

The SYM package was developed by Stylianos Dimas and may be found in Appendix A of his thesis at http://nemertes.lis.upatras.gr/jspui/bitstream/10889/1697/1/thesis.pdf

Comment: Because we are an English language site, it would be appropriate (and kind) of you to point out that the entire text of that thesis--including the comments in the code--is in Greek.

Comment: @whuber http://www.internationalmathematicasymposium.org/IMS2006/IMS2006_CD/articles/Dimas.pdf

Comment: @whuber Yes, that's a bit of a problem. I'm not recommending anybody read the text of the thesis, just grep the relevant Mathematica package out of the appendix. As belisarius points out, there are a few English-language papers in the literature concerning the package.

Comment: @belisarius Thanks. That seems like a version of the reference supplied by the OP.

Comment: Professor Tsoubelis can be contacted here http://www.math.upatras.gr/~tsoubeli/contact.htm

Comment: Dimas also says in the preface to Appendix A that you can contact him for a copy of the package at spawn@math.upatras.gr According to his most recent paper, that e-mail is still valid (although he's now in Brazil).

Comment: Thanks @Xerxes. I e-mailed Dimas and he sent me a copy of the package. It turns out there is some online documentation here: http://www.math.upatras.gr/~spawn/SYM_html/guide/SYMOverview.html .

Answer (score 6):

I recommend ["Introduction to Symmetry Analysis" by Cantwell](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=6578). It comes with a [quite powerful Mathematica package](https://web.stanford.edu/~cantwell/SymmetryAnalysisSoftware/), with numerous examples included.

Comment: Your link to the Mathematica package is dead.

Comment: @Geremia both work for me, perhaps you can’t access the address due to country restrictions?

Comment: @CATrevillian I changed the Mathematica package link that from the author's website.