# Conservation of area solving a PDE via finite difference scheme

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

I have two PDEs that describe the movement of fluid:

1. $h_t + [h^3(1-h)^3((1+\varepsilon h)\sin \theta - \varepsilon h_\theta \cos \theta]_\theta$ = 0
2. $h_t - [h^3(1-h)^3 \varepsilon h_\theta]_\theta$ = 0

You will note that 1) reduces to 2) at $\theta = 0$.

I solve these two PDE's via a finite difference scheme. The first as follows

```
n = 1001; ϵ = 0.5; 
ds = Pi/(n - 1); 
ClearAll[dh, t]; endtime = 100; 
dh[h_List] := With[{ϵ = 0.5, s = Array[#1 & , n, {-(Pi/2), Pi/2}], d1 = ListCorrelate[{-0.5, 0, 0.5}/ds, #1] & , d2 = ListCorrelate[{1, -2, 1}/ds^2, #1] & }, 
    ((-1 + h)^2*h^2*(3*(1 - 2*h)*ϵ*Cos[s]*d1[#1]^2 + (-1 + h)*h*Cos[s]*(1 + h*ϵ - ϵ*d2[#1]) + (-3 + h*(6 + (-5 + 8*h)*ϵ))*d1[#1]*Sin[s]) & )[Join[{0.99}, h, {0.99}]]];

h0 = Table[Piecewise[{{0.01, -0.25510204081632654 < θ < 0.25510204081632654}}, 0.99], {θ, -(Pi/2), Pi/2, ds}]; 

Clear[h]; 
sol = With[{h = (h[#1][t] & ) /@ Range[n]}, NDSolveValue[{D[h, t] == dh[h], (h /. t -> 0) == h0}, Head /@ h, {t, 0, endtime}]]; valh = Transpose[(#1["ValuesOnGrid"] & ) /@ sol]; 
ti = Flatten[sol[[1]]["Grid"]]; 
s = Array[#1 & , n, {-(Pi/2), Pi/2}]; h = ListInterpolation[valh, {ti, s}, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

This solves reasonably quickly. I check area conservation between $t = 0$ and $t = 100$ with the following:

```
Table[Integrate[Interpolation[Table[{θ, 0.99 - h[t, θ]}, {θ, -(Pi/2), Pi/2, Pi/3000}], InterpolationOrder -> 1][θ], {θ, -(Pi/2), Pi/2}], {t, {0, 100}}]
```

An error of $0.96 \%$, which I can reduce to $0.19\%$ by increasing $n$ to 2001. I am happy with this.

However, my problem comes in when solving the second PDE (which I feel in theory should be easier as it is a simplification of the first one). I solve in the same manner (initial condition is flipped due to minus sign and physical reasons).

```
n = 1001; ϵ = 0.5; 
ds = Pi/(n - 1); 
ClearAll[dz, t]; endtime = 100; 
dz[z_List] := With[{ϵ = 0.5, s = Array[#1 & , n, {-(Pi/2), Pi/2}], d1 = ListCorrelate[{-0.5, 0, 0.5}/ds, #1] & , 
     d2 = ListCorrelate[{1, -2, 1}/ds^2, #1] & }, ((-ϵ)*(-1 + z)^2*z^2*((-3 + 6*z)*d1[#1]^2 + (-1 + z)*z*d2[#1]) & )[Join[{0.01}, z, {0.01}]]]; 

z0 = Table[Piecewise[{{0.99, -0.25510204081632654 < x < 0.25510204081632654}}, 0.01], {x, -(Pi/2), Pi/2, ds}]; 

Clear[z]; 
solz = With[{z = (z[#1][t] & ) /@ Range[n]}, NDSolveValue[{D[z, t] == dz[z], (z /. t -> 0) == z0}, Head /@ z, {t, 0, endtime}]]; 
  valz = Transpose[(#1["ValuesOnGrid"] & ) /@ solz]; 
tiz = Flatten[solz[[1]]["Grid"]]; 
s = Array[#1 & , n, {-(Pi/2), Pi/2}]; z = ListInterpolation[valz, {tiz, s}, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

Firstly, with $n = 1001$ this takes an age to run on my machine. Secondly, when I check conservation of area for PDE 2.

```
Table[Integrate[Interpolation[Table[{θ, z[t, θ] - 0.01}, {θ, -(Pi/2), Pi/2, Pi/3000}], InterpolationOrder -> 1][θ], {θ, -(Pi/2), Pi/2}], {t, {0, 100}}]
```

I get a massive $13.5 \%$ discrepancy between the initial and final error. I could in theory reduce this by increasing $n$, however I tried with $n = 2001$ and the code was running for 8+ hours before I aborted it.

Does anyone have any pointers? My ultimate aim is to have PDE 2 conserving area and solving quickly. Does my FD scheme need some work?

All comments and questions welcomed.

**EDIT**

By adding the option `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}` to `NDSolveValue` for equation 2 I can solve for $n = 5001$ points in about 30 minutes. This still gives an intolerable error of $\approx 5 \%$.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using an FDM scheme instead of using `NDSolve` "out of the box"?  Could you also describe what the initial and boundary conditions are for this problem?  Spreading of a droplet on some sort of wetting surface?

Comment: @drN I wish to use a FDM as I want to understand each aspect of the code, rather than just putting it into a black box. The initial condition is box function, that - as you correctly state - describes an interface of an initial blob of fluid. The boundary conditions are that far from the blob (ie. ) the interface stays on the surface, so $h(-\pi/2) = h(\pi/2) = 0$. I actually us 0.01 in my code other wise the PDE becomes 0 and nothing moves.

Comment: -1 for showing the wrong equation. There should be a minus sign before the $h_t$ in the second equation. (This mistake ruined my whole night! ) I'll retract the downvote after you correct the mistake anyway…

Comment: @xzczd Sincere apologies for the typo in the equation. It was correct in the code for the finite difference scheme but I made a mistake typing it for the purpose of the question !

Comment: Downvote retracted. This is a interesting problem after all :)

Comment: @drN Strangely, `NDSolve` can't find the **correct** solution directly while in principle it should. (My answer below is actually a self implementation of `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> False, 
 "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 900, "MinPoints" -> 900,
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}` option in `NDSolve`.)

Comment: @xzczd I had solved a similar 3rd order nonlinear problem using NDSolve.  One could also use a method of similarity solutions (analytical method).  I wonder if any method of similiarity type solution and the manipulations required have been done in mathematica...?

Comment: @drN Just read the material you linked below, interesting. [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20476/1871) and [this](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/570) package might be related, but I can't tell how to use them…

Comment: @ojlm  My [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133253/1063) to question 129183 appears to be what you need for your second equation.  It produces high accuracy in less than a minute.  Thanks to [xzczd](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1871/xzczd) for pointing out the connection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Eq. 2 Results**

As I noted in a comment above, my [answer to question 129183](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133253/1063) provides an accurate solution to the second equation in the present question.

[image]

where the eleven curves correspond to `t == Range[0, 200, 20]`. The computation required only 200 grid points, took less than a minute, and conserved area exactly.  The method used was essentially the same as that given in the present question but with spatial discretization given by

```
(ϵ (-(((1 + 1/2 (-z[-1 + i] - z[i]))^3 (-z[-1 + i] + z[i]) (z[-1 + i] + z[i])^3)/(8 d)) + 
     ((1 + 1/2 (-z[i] - z[1 + i]))^3 (-z[i] + z[1 + i]) (z[i] + z[1 + i])^3)/(8 d)))/d
```

It is easy to see that summing this expression over `i` leaves only the difference between the first and last terms of the array

```
((1 + 1/2 (-z[i] - z[1 + i]))^3 (-z[i] + z[1 + i]) (z[i] + z[1 + i])^3)/(8 d)))
```

which are negligible until well past `t == 100`.  Thus, area conservation is accomplished not by using a large grid but rather by the discretization itself.  In contrast, the discretization used in the present question is

```
-ϵ (-1 + z[i])^2 z[i]^2 (((-3 + 6 z[i]) (-z[-1 + i] + z[1 + i])^2)/(4 d^2) + 
  ((-1 + z[i]) z[i] (z[-1 + i] - 2 z[i] + z[1 + i]))/d^2)
```

which does not sum conveniently.  It is interesting to compare the results above with those from the solutions obtained from the "Edit" at the end of the present question.  For `n == 5001`,

[image]

which is similar to the first plot in this answer.  However, with the grid size reduced to `n == 1001`,

[image]

which is noticeably different.  Results depend on the grid size and only slowly converge to the first plot in this answer.  Spatial discretization that mirrors the symmetry of the PDE makes a big difference.

**Eq. 1 Results**

As requested by ojlm, here are results for the first equation in the question, obtained using a difference scheme similar to that used above for the second equation.

```
bound = 0.25510204081632654;
upper = 1/100; lower = 1 - upper;
range = {L, R} = {-Pi/2, Pi/2};
endtime = 100;
ϵ = 1/2;
n = 200; d = (R - L)/n;
vars = Table[u[i, t], {i, 2, n}]; u[1, t] = lower; u[n + 1, t] = lower; 
eq = Table[dup = (u[i + 1, t] - u[i, t])/d; dum = (u[i, t] - u[i - 1, t])/d; 
    up = (u[i + 1, t] + u[i, t])/2; um = (u[i, t] + u[i - 1, t])/2;
    D[u[i, t], t] == ((up^3 (1 - up)^3) (ϵ dup Cos[L + (i - 1/2) d] - 
        (1 + ϵ up) Sin[L + (i - 1/2) d]) - 
        (um^3 (1 - um)^3) (ϵ dum Cos[L + (i - 3/2) d] - 
        (1 + ϵ um) Sin[L + (i - 3/2) d]))/d, {i, 2, n}];
init = Table[u[i, 0] == Piecewise[{{upper, -bound < L + (i - 1) d < bound}}, lower], 
    {i, 2, n}];
s = NDSolveValue[{eq, init}, vars, {t, 0, endtime}];
ListLinePlot[Evaluate@Table[Join[{1 - lower}, 
    Table[1 - s[[i - 1]] /. t -> tt, {i, 2, n}], {1 - lower}], 
    {tt, 0, endtime, endtime/10}], DataRange -> range, PlotRange -> 1]
```

[image]

Conserved area is constant to of order 0.01%.  Note that only 200 grid points are required, and increasing the number of grid points to 1000 has no visible impact on the plot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So if I understand correctly, you have not differentiated equation 2 before discretising. Suppose now I wished to discretise equation 1 in the same manner, my attempt is as follows (as per your answer 129183)

`D[u[i, t], 
  t] == (up^3 (1 - 
        up)^3 ((1 + \[Epsilon]*up) Sin[(i - 1) d] - \[Epsilon]*
        Cos[(i - 1) d] dup) - 
    um^3 (1 - um)^3 ((1 + \[Epsilon]*um) Sin[(i - 1) d] - \[Epsilon]*
        Cos[(i - 1) d] dum)) /d`

However this does not work. I presume a problem with the $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ terms?

Comment: @ojlm  Your z0 and h0 are defined differently.  Consequently, Eq 2 with initial and boundary conditions is not the same as the limit of Eq 1 with initial and boundary conditions for small `θ`.  Is this intentional?

Comment: @ojlm  Try `D[u[i, t], t] == ((up^3 (1 - up)^3) (ϵ dup Cos[L + (i - 1/2) d] - (1 + ϵ up) Sin[L + (i - 1/2) d]) - (um^3 (1 - um)^3) (ϵ dum Cos[L + (i - 3/2) d] - (1 + ϵ um) Sin[L + (i - 3/2) d]))/d` (with your definition of `h0`).

Comment: yes, this is intentional, purely due to the physics under consideration during the derivation of equation 1 and equation 2. That was one mistake I had made. Thanks for editing your answer with a full solution for equation 1. It is much much faster than my version.

Answer (score 13):

## Partly `NDSolve`-based solution

Use a higher **even** order spatial grid to discretize the PDE to an ODE set seems to be a good approach. The definition of `pdetoode` can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871):

```
bound = 0.25510204081632654;
upper = 99/100; lower = 1 - upper;
range = {L, R} = {-Pi/2, Pi/2};
endtime = 100;
eqn = With[{h = h[t, θ], ϵ = 5/10}, 
   0 == -D[h, t] + D[h^3 (1 - h)^3 ϵ D[h, θ], θ]];
ic = h[0, θ] == 
   Simplify`PWToUnitStep@Piecewise[{{upper, -bound < θ < bound}}, lower];
bc = {h[t, L] == lower, h[t, R] == lower};

points = 900;
grid = Array[# &, points, range];
xdifforder = 10;
ptoo = pdetoode[h[t, θ], t, grid, xdifforder];
del = Delete[#, {{1}, {-1}}] &;
var = h /@ grid;
Attributes[h] = NHoldAll;
odeqn = del@ptoo@eqn;
odeic = del@ptoo@ic;
odebc = bc // ptoo;
sollst = NDSolveValue[{odeqn, odeic, odebc} // N, var, {t, 0, endtime}, 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {19.372995, Null} *)

sol = rebuild[sollst, grid];

(# - #2)/# & @@ Table[NIntegrate[sol[t, θ], {θ, L, R}], {t, {0, endtime}}]
(* 0.00203278 *)

Animate[Plot[sol[t, th], {th, L, R}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}], {t, 0, endtime}]
```

[image]

Notice a even difference order is necessary, if you set e.g. `xdifforder = 3`, you'll get a erroneous result like:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Result sliced at `t = endtime`.*

---

## Fully `NDSolve`-based solution

One may think the solution above is a self implementation of `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> False, "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 900, "MinPoints" -> 900, "DifferenceOrder" -> 10}}` option in `NDSolve`, but it's not true. Check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/129183/1871) for more details. Actually if we directly add this option to `NDSolve`, we'll obtain a solution quite similar to those we get with odd order in partly `NDSolve`-based solution!:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Result sliced at `t = endtime`.*

Inspired by the truth, I found that setting an **odd** `"DifferenceOrder"` inside `NDSolve` will resolve the problem:

```
mol[n_Integer, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}
mol[tf:False|True,sf_:Automatic]:={"MethodOfLines",
"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions"->{tf,"ScaleFactor"->sf}}

sold = NDSolveValue[{eqn, ic, bc}, h, {t, 0, endtime}, {θ, L, R}, 
    Method -> Union[mol@False, mol[900, 9]], MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {9.774524, Null} *)

(# - #2)/# & @@ Table[NIntegrate[sold[t, θ], {θ, L, R}], {t, {0, endtime}}]
(* 0.00342644 *)

Animate[Plot[sold[t, th], {th, L, R}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}], {t, 0, endtime}]
```

The animation is similar to the one above so I'd like to omit it here.

Comment: 有你解不出的微分方程吗请问 :)

Comment: @yode 有，而且有很多……只是最近弄清楚了``NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative``的用法所以这几天藉此解出了几个历史遗留问题而已……

Comment: Very interesting problem: a similarity solution as recommended by Witelski [(link 1)](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319230412) [(link 2)](https://www.amazon.com/Methods-Mathematical-Modelling-Differential-Undergraduate-ebook/dp/B015K8JL56/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1476545085&sr=8-1&keywords=witelski) could help too.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but it still produces a huge (and unacceptable) error of $\approx 7\%$

Comment: @ojlm Notice I only used `900` points and it only takes `14` seconds to get the solution.

Comment: Ah yes, I've upped it to `5000` points to get the error down to $\approx 2 \%$, One thing I am a little confused about is the role of ` `Simplify`PWToUnitStep` I can't seem to fine `PWToUnitStep` in the documentation

Comment: @ojlm Yes, it's undocumented, it's a function that'll change `Piecewise` to `UnitStep`. We need to represent the i.c. with `UnitStep` because `pdetoode` internally makes use of the `Listable` attribute of function (when dealing with e.g. `x+1` it simply does the replacement e.g. `x+1/.x->{1,2,3}`) while `Piecewise` isn't `Listable`. (Well, maybe I should directly add it to `pdetoode` function. )

Comment: @ojlm I noticed we don't need to limit ourself to 4th order, and `NDSolve` can also be used for solving the problem. See my edit.

Comment: @xzczd Is there a maximum number of points this can be used with? For example, if I set `xdifforder = 4` and `points = 10000` I get an error  `"\!\({t, 0, 200}[\"ValuesOnGrid\"]\) cannot be used as a variable."`. However, if I set the `points = 2000` I get no such error.

Comment: @xzczd There seems to be only certain combinations of `points` and `xdifforder` that work. I can't seem to spot the pattern, but small numbers of points seem to be more successful, which is of course the opposite of what I want as I wish to reduce the error

Comment: @xzczd Btw, I am getting these errors when solving the first PDE `0 == D[h, t] + 
   D[h^3 (1 - h)^3 ( (1 + \[Epsilon]*h) Sin[\[Theta]] - 
       Cos[\[Theta]] \[Epsilon] D[h, \[Theta]]), \[Theta]]]` with `upper = 0.31` and `lower = 0.99`

Comment: @ojlm The error is because `NDSolveValue` returns unevaluated. I guess you also got the warning `ndsdtc`. Anyway, try setting `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> {Automatic, "TimeConstraint" -> 100}}` in `NDSolveValue` if you still want to increase points. (I do suggest you to simply use a higher difference order rather than increase points excessively, because as mentioned in the update, using a higher difference order turns out to be a much more efficient way to reduce the error. )

Comment: @xzczd I wanted to accept both, as I found both helpful in deepening my understand of Mathematica and this problem