# I want MathLie setup for mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, packages

I tried to find Math lie in Mathematica but I didn't find setup.
Can anyone share Math lie setup for Mathematica?

Comment: If you mean you can't find where to download, check this post:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139419/1871

Comment: @xzczd
Thank you sir